# Dynamically update static webpage with python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, raspberry-pi, rfid

So I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 with a rfid scanner and wrote a script in python that logs people in and out of our attendance system, connects to our postgresql database and returns some data like how much overtime they have and whether their action was a login or logout.

This data is meant to be displayed on a very basic webpage (that is not even on a server or anything) that just serves as a graphical interface to display said data.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to dynamically display that data that my python script returns on the webpage without having to refresh it. I'd like it to simply fade in the information, keep it there for a few seconds and then have it fade out again (at which point the system becomes available again to have someone else login or logout).

Currently I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to edit the Html File and Chrome with the extension "LivePage" to then automatically update the page which is obviously a horrible solution.

I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction as to how I can accoumplish this in a comprehensible and reasonably elegant way.

TL;DR: I want to display the results of my python script on my web page without having to refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a html file and send XHR request to the primary one every x seconds .

```
setTimeout(function(){     
$.get( "yourPrimaryFile.xyz", function( data ) {
      $( "body" )
        .append(data) // Mr.X
    }) }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume an more or less obvious solution like building a REST API with e.g. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and using some javascript framework (e.g. [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)) on the frontend is out of scope / too much?

Besides that I can only think of using 'plain' jquery or similar frameworks, which is more or less what you do currently.

I would recommend trying the flask/angular combination. A simple app (few API endpoints for login and out and a few checks) and a basic website with dynamic content is setup pretty quickly.

Comment: I've tried using Django before to solve this problem but I still cannot figure out how I get the data from my script to be displayed on the webpage whenever a chip has been scanned.

Answer (score 0):

To update page data without delay you need to use websockets. 
There is no need in using heavy frameworks.

1. Once page is loaded first time you open websocket with js and listen to it.
2. Every time you read a tag you post all necessary data to this open socket and it instantly appear on client side.